# C++, 'template' keyword before emplace_back(), how does it works?

Tags: c++, vector, clion

I was studying Algorithm in C++ using CLion.
I'm currently using **Windows 10, Clion 2021.3.3 with bundled MingW**
I was working on code, Merge Sort algorithm, and I had chance to use vector.emplace_back().
Whenever I try to use ****vector.emplace_back()**** my CLion complier tries to make my code like this.

```
v.template emplace_back();
```

I know that Clion is based on Clang-tidy which tries to make my code better and prettier, 
 but how come this code works?
I had no problem or error when I was compiling my code in Clion. 
I know that most of us simply just use ****vector.emplace_back()**** or ****vector.push_back()****, and it works well in any other IDEs.

I tried to run above usage in both Visual Studio 2022 (C++ 20) and repl.it.
In repl.it, it worked and Visual Studio returned me C2059 syntax error : 'template'. 
So I looked up [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) and [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) to figure out this usage, and neither of them mentioned about this kind of usage.

I do understand that there are some differences between IDEs but it would be great someone who can answer how does my code works.
Below code is my Merge Sort code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define endl '\n'
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
vector<T> merge(vector<T>& arr1, vector<T>& arr2) {
    vector<T> merged;

    auto iter1 = arr1.begin();
    auto iter2 = arr2.begin();

    while(iter1 != arr1.end() && iter2 != arr2.end()) {
        if (*iter1 < *iter2) {
            merged.template emplace_back(*iter1);
            iter1++;
        }
        else {
            merged.template emplace_back(*iter2);
            iter2++;
        }
    }
    if (iter1 != arr1.end()) {
        for (; iter1 != arr1.end(); iter1++)
            merged.template emplace_back(*iter1);
    }
    else {
        for (; iter2 != arr2.end(); iter2++)
            merged.template emplace_back(*iter2);
    }
    return merged;
}

template<typename T>
vector<T> merge_sort(vector<T> arr) {
    if (arr.size() > 1) {
        auto mid = size_t(arr.size() / 2);
        auto left = merge_sort<T>(vector<T>(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + mid));
        auto right = merge_sort<T>(vector<T>(arr.begin() + mid, arr.end()));
        return merge<T>(left, right);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Here is my CMakeList.txt which is nothing special.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(Data)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(Data main.cpp)
```

To wrap it up, it would be grateful if someone can tell how does my code works fine, and where should I refer to to to solve my question?

```
merged.template emplace_back(*iter1);
```

Respectfully,

Comment: `template` is not required there. [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) might interest you.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the tool recommending that change. There's no need to disambiguate this for the parser unless you have explicit `<>` in there.

Comment: Please also read ["Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h") and ["Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice").  You should also think carefully about the possible impact of `#define endl '\n'` .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is wrong with your clang-tidy setup in CLion, but I cannot reproduce the message.

In any case, the message is wrong. The keyword `template` may be prefixed before a name only if the name is a template-id (except in one case that doesn't matter here), so `v.template emplace_back<>();` would be allowed, but `v.template emplace_back();` isn't. Some compilers are quite lax of enforcing this rule, so they will accept the version with `template` prefix as well, but technically that is wrong.

If for some reason you used a template argument list as in `merged.template emplace_back<>();`, for which there is absolutely no reason on `emplace_back`, then you would indeed need to add the `template` prefix, because the type of `merged` in your code is dependent on the template parameter `T` and so `template` is needed to disambiguate the `<` in the template argument list from being a less-than operator without needing to instantiate the template.

Comment: Feel like reinstalling Clion would be better option for me since I hadn't manipulated any option in my Clion. Thanks for your answer by the way.